# Multidimensional array of functions

Tags: javascript

How can I make this work:

```
q = {}

q[0] = new Array()

q[0].push(function()
{
   console.log("whatup")
})

q[0]() // currently prints "q[0] is not a function"
```

Of course, it shouldn't execute until I call it. I tried nesting it inside another function as a return value, but nothing works :(

Comment: Someone deleted their answer that had helpful information. You're actually creating an object filled with arrays, because you initialize q with `{}`, to create an array of arrays, use `q = []` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array, but you're only accessing the first dimension at the end (which is another array). Try `q[0][0]()`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the value in q[0] is the new Array() that you assigned to it -- not a function.

These lines:

```
q[0].push(function()
{
   console.log("whatup")
})
```

will put the function as the first element of the new Array you assigned to q[0] in the second line.  So instead of this:

```
q[0]() // currently prints "q[0] is not a function"
```

You're really wanting to do this:

```
q[0][0]()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work but you're calling the array. To call the function you need to do

```
q[0][0]()
```